# How to specify path in META-INF/context.xml for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm using Tomcat 7 and would like to set the context root of a war file in the war file itself and have Tomcat autodeploy and pick up this path.
   I thought I found the way to do it by putting a context.xml in the META-INF directory of the war which contains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/somepath/myapp"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I think it's loaded by http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/SetContextPropertiesRule.html which states it loads everything but the path!

I know I can name the war somepath#myapp.war and it will pick it up but I also deploy to weblogic which isn't happy with a name like this.

Is there some setting I can use to have the path work from the context.xml above?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Context `path` attribute is ignored unless the path is specified in a hard-coded `Context` in `server.xml`, which is strongly discouraged, and doesn't take multilevel paths.

The name of the war file, or the name of the Context xml file in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/hostname` becomes the `path` of the deployed application.

In your case the latter of the two above is the solution, just make sure you put the `.war` file outside of the designated `appBase` for the Host, or you'll deploy the app twice.

In: `conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp#path.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context docBase="/some/path/to/myapp.war">
</Context>
```

Comment: Hi, Is that possible to dynamically populate this docBase attribute at build time? My requirement is to populate it with the latest build number from maven. please reply

Comment: Hi dharam. It should be possible via resource filtering (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). However, I prefer to do it via Tomcat-deployment script: https://github.com/EBIBioSamples/myequivalents/blob/master/myequivalents-web/deploy2tomcat.sh. This allows you to build once and deploy on multiple Tomcat installations, and also to deploy without Maven.

Answer (score 2):

In /tomcat7/conf/server.xml add below lines inside the  element and restart Tomcat to make changes take place.

*change "mycom" to your application name.

```
<Context path="" docBase="mycom">
  <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
<Context path="ROOT" docBase="ROOT">
  <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

This will make the default root application appear under context root "/ROOT".

Now your app is accessible at "/" and "/mycom" as well!

Answer (score 1):

add copyXML="true" to Host config inside $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml like

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" copyXML="true">
```

Comment: I was hoping that this would work, but it ended up still ignoring the value. this used to work in older versions of Tomcat, but not in Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you load your application.war to a directory Tomcat isn't aware of, how can it read anything in your war file?  The correct place to add this information is in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml - this is part of Tomcat and Tomcat can read this file and find out where your application is and deploy it.  There's more on [how to set up JNDI in Tomcat](http://www.databaseapplications.com.au/jndi.jsp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.