# How to configure Tomcat to use a context path like /webapps/myapp

Tags: configuration, tomcat9

After reading that I shouldn't set the context in `server.xml`, I tried creating `META-INF/context.xml`. The `Resource` definitions are read ok but the `path` attribute is ignored.

```
<Context path="/webapps/uebersetzung" docBase="UebersetzungWeb">
    <Resource ....
</Context>
```

The war file is `UebersetzungWeb` and I want to set the context path to `webapps/uebersetzung`. (I am migrating a WebSphere app and the context path is hard-coded in many places)

So far, the only way I found to do this is to rename the war to `webapps#uebersetzung` before deployment.

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Please see if this helps:
[Tomcat 9 Context Path Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589451/apache-tomcat-9-0-0-m10-change-context-path-in-meta-inf-context-xml-not-working)

Comment: @TechFree thanks. It seems to confirm my approach: "I personally found the easiest solution to be simply to name your WAR file appropriately"